# CUDA: How to find index of extrema in sub matrices?

Tags: cuda

I have a large rectangular matrix NxM in GPU memory, stored as 1-dimensional array in row-by-row representation. Let us say that this matrix is actually composed of submatrices of size nxm. For simplicity, assume that N is a multiple of n and same with M and m. Let us say, the data type of the array is float or double.

What is an efficient method to find the index of the extrema in each sub-matrix? For example, how to find the 1-dimensional index of the maximum element of each submatrix and write down those indices in some array.

Comment: The most appropriate solution will depend on the magnitude of `n` relative to the warp size. There isn't a general solution. If n is approaching `N`, then `cublasIsamin` is probably as efficient as anything you will write yourself.

Comment: @talonmies I tried to point out this important differentiation (whether N=n*2 or N=n*10000) in my answer. Although `cublasIsamin` sounds like good option for the second approach that I sketched, the problem is that is only operates on an 1D array (with a possible stride given in incx, but still 1D) - so it's not applicable for 2D sub-matrices

Answer (score 2):

I can hardly imagine to be *so* self-confident (or arrogant?) to say that one particular solution is the *"most efficient way"* to do something.

However, some thoughts (without the claim to cover the "most efficient" solution) :

I think that there are basically two "orthogonal" ways of approaching this

- For all sub-matrices in parallel: Find the extremum sequentially
- For all sub-matrices sequentially: Find the extremum in parallel

The question which one is more appropriate probably depends on the sizes of the matrices. You mentioned that *"N is a multiple of n"* (similarly for M and m). Let's the matrix of size `M x N` is composed of `a*b` sub-matrices of size `m x n`.

For the first approach, one could simply let each thread take care of one sub-matrix, with a trivial loop like

```
for (all elements of my sub-matrix) max = element > max ? element : max;
```

The prerequisite here is that `a*b` is "reasonably large". That is, when you can launch this kernel for, let's say, 10000 sub-matrices, then this could already bring a good speedup.

In contrast to that, in the second approach, each kernel (with all its threads) would take care of one sub-matrix. In this case, the kernel could be a standard "reduction" kernel. (The reduction is often presented an example for "computing the sum/product of the elements of an array", but it works for any binary associative operation, so instead of computing the sum or product, one can basically use the same kernel for computing the minimum or maximum). So the kernel would be launched for each sub-matrix, and this would only make sense when the sub-matrix is "reasonably large".

However, in *both* cases, one has to consider the general performance guidelines. Particularly, since in this case, the operation is obviously memory-bound (and not compute-bound), one has to make sure that the accesses to global memory (that is, to the matrix itself) are coalesced, and that the occupancy that is created by the kernel is as high as possible.

EDIT: Of course, one could consider to somehow combine these approaches, but I think that they are at least showing the most important directions of the space of available options.